# Custom tab view using react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-router-flux

I'm trying to create a custom tab view using react-native-router-flux, my scene is looking like this:

```
<Tabs key="tabRoot" component={Container} navBar={NavBar}>
   <Scene key="tab1" component={Tab1} tabBarLabel="Tab 1" hideNavBar />
   <Scene key="tab2" component={Tab2} tabBarLabel="Tab 2" hideNavBar />
   <Scene key="tab2" component={Tab2} tabBarLabel="Tab 3" hideNavBar />
</Tabs>
```

And like it to look like this:

[image: custom tab view]

So difference to "normal" tab view is that tab bar is in the middle, and top portion of screen is reserved for another view ("foo"), and tab content views should be under tab bar (where it says now "Tab 1 content"). So my question is, how can I achieve this? :)

Comment: Is the top static content or tied to the tab view in any way? Is the tab bar meant for actual navigation or just switch out content on this specific screen?

Comment: No, it's not (at least directly) tied to tab views.

Comment: @ovaris I have the same problem. Did you end up with a solution?

Comment: @fcicer unfortunately I gave up, didn't use rn-router-flux for that view